# How To implement Google Places Text Box Prediction on ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-maps

I am creating a website in which I am using a master page and I want to use the text box prediction in my content page. But the prediction is not working. But I need to do this **using ASP controls and not HTML**.
My code is:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('FromTxtBx'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                alert(mesg);
            });
        });
    </script>   <br />
    <div class="row">
    <form class="col s10" runat="server">
        <br />
      <div class="input-field">
<div class="col s12 m4 l5">

    <label for="last_name">FROM</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="FromTxtBx" class="validate"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FromPred" />
    
              </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="input-field col s7 push-s1">
<div class="col s12 m4 l8">

    <label for="last_name1">TO</label>   
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="last_name1"></asp:TextBox>
            
</div>
             </div>
       </form>
         </div>
    
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this this will give you all address element in textbox then you can call use as you like and hide these text boxes

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
<title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<style>
  #locationField, #controls {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
  }
  #autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 99%;
  }
  .label {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    color: #303030;
  }
  #address {
    border: 1px solid #000090;
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
    width: 480px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  #address td {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .field {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .slimField {
    width: 80px;
  }
  .wideField {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #locationField {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <h1> Address Lookup </h1>


<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }

    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

</form>
```

Comment: After few seconds in the textbox where you type input , appears "error ... "

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to do:

1. Have you confirmed the call to the Google API takes place? Do this with the IE Developer Tools (press F12) or use Fiddler to see the call
2. But if #1 works fine, the most likely issue is that you are doing a GetElementById and since you have a master page, it is possible that the name was expanded to something like $masterpage$control$fromtextbox. This happens to avoid naming collissions.

Right click on your page, view source and confirm this is the case. If it is, don't use that name, instead use a different selector.